# Need QMediaPlayer to play mp3 data in memory

Tags: android, ios, qt, mp3, qmediaplayer

I guess small audio clips are necessary for many applications, thus I would expect QT have support playing mp3 in memory slices. Maybe decode mp3 data to wav data in memory may be one solution, but that needs time to decode all data first. For real time application, it is not a good idea. It also doesn't make sense to store mp3_data in a file and ask QMediaPlayer to play that, the performance is unacceptable.

This is my code after many searches by google, including stackoverflow:

```
        m_buffer.setBuffer(&mp3_data_in_memory);
        m_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(), &m_buffer);
        m_player.play();
```

where m_buffer is a QBuffer instance, and mp3_data_in_memory is a QByteArray one; m_player is a QMediaPlayer instance.

I got some information that the code here doesn't work in MacOS and iOS, but I am running on Android now.

Does anyone have a solution for Android system? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work because the `media` property [requires](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#media-prop) a valid `QMediaContent` instance:

> Setting this property to a null QMediaContent will cause the player to
>   discard all information relating to the current media source and to
>   cease all I/O operations related to that media.

There's also no way of telling the `QMediaPlayer` what format the data is in, you're just dumping raw data on it.  In principle `QMediaResource` can hold this information, but it requires a url and is regarded as null without it.

As you may have guessed, `QMediaPlayer` and the related classes are high-level constructs not designed for this sort of thing.  You need to use a [`QAudioDecoder`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiodecoder.html#details) to actually decode the raw data, and pipe the output to a [`QAudioOutput`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaudiooutput.html#details) to hear it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But there is no luck to make QAudioDecoder works in Android, iOS and Desktop. I eventually choose mpg123 to decode and output to QAudioOutput.